# After revoke a client certificate with easy-rsa3 index.txt has not been updated

Tags: openvpn, self-signed-certificate

I have an OpenVPN easy-rsa server for self-signed certificate. I revoked one of client certificate using `.\easyrsa revoke mycert` command. The command returned normally, but in the index.txt the revoked certificate is not marked as R and still remain V status without expired date-time. Under easyrsa3/pki/issued directory, the revoked certificate is not exist.

Is my certificate revoked correctly? If not how can I fix this inconsistency?